# How to fix "styles$6.makeStyles is not a function" in jest unit tests?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, material-ui

I am working in a form component, inside this form I am using **DateTimePicker** and **MuiPickersUtilsProvider** in oder to show two DateTime fields. Everything compiles and run fine, but writing the unit test I am getting a compilation error:

```
    TypeError: styles$6.makeStyles is not a function

       9 | import Tab from '@material-ui/core/Tab';
      10 | import DateFnsUtils from '@date-io/date-fns';
    > 11 | import { DateTimePicker, MuiPickersUtilsProvider } from '@material-ui/pickers';
         | ^
      12 | 
      13 | import {
      14 |     inputProps,
```

In order to fix it, I create a component and wrap the Form and other components needed with `withStyles(styles)` but still I got the same issue. At some point a removed from the project all the references to **@material-ui/pickers** and everything works fine.

This is how I tried to fix the problem, I created a wrapper component **TestWrapperComponent** with the following code:

```
import React from 'react';
import {createMuiTheme, MuiThemeProvider} from "@material-ui/core";
import Form from '../Form';

const Theme = createMuiTheme({...});

export default withStyles(styles)(class TestWrapperComponent extends React.Component {

    render() {
        return <StateProvider initialState={{
            displaySuccessMsg: false,
        }} reducer={reducer}>
            <MuiThemeProvider theme={Theme}>
                 <Form/>
            </MuiThemeProvider>
        </StateProvider>
    }
});
```

The Form component is named **Form**

I was expecting that `withStyles(styles)` would fix the issue, but I haven't had success. I also search all over google, and have not find anything meaningful.

Answer (score 1):

You can mock modules used by MUI components

```js
jest.mock('@material-ui/core/styles', () => ({
  createStyles: () => () => ({}),
  makeStyles: () => () => ({}),
  withStyles: () => () => ({}),
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

Just update to material-ui/core v4